# Wait for AsyncMethod in C# Constructor

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

**Given:**
I've a class  which manages user storage. Now when creating the class I want to ensure indexes which is a asynchronous method. Currently i just call wait, but i don't feel comfortable to it as I'm a little concerned about unexpected behaviors like hanging threads.

```
public MongoUserStorage(IMongoDatabase database)
{
    userCollection = database.GetCollection<MongoUser>("Users");
    roleCollection = database.GetCollection<MongoUserRole>("UserRoles");

    CreateIndexesAsync().Wait();
}
```

**Question:**

What is best way to handle this asynchous mehtod? (I want to be sure that the indexes are present after the class is instantiated)

Just do: `CreateIndexesAsync().Wait();`

or

```
var task = CreateIndexesAsync();
task.ConfigureAwait(false);
task.Wait();
```

Or any better solution ?

Comment: `ConfigureAwait` does nothing if used this way. As you may noticed, it returns `TaskAwaitable` that is supposed to be `await`-ed instead of the task. The task itself is unaffected. I think you are stuck with what you are doing currently (along with all the related risks).

Comment: "concerned about unexpected behaviors like hanging threads" I think you should understand the issue first. That allows you to conclude that this is safe.

Answer (score 3):

You are referring to the classic `SynchronizationContext` deadlock. As long as `CreateIndexesAsync` does not use a `SynchronizationContext` which is very unlikely this is completely safe.

Research what `ConfigureAwait` does and how to use it. Your current usage demonstrates that you don't really know enough. `task.ConfigureAwait(false);` is a no-op because it creates a new `TaskAwaiter` and throws it away.